# The download button does not appear to download the VR Apps

Tags: applications, samsung, samsung-galaxy-s, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge, samsung-gear-vr

My phone is not allowing me to download the VR app for my Samsung Gear... The download button is not coming up for me to tap.I tried restarting my phone several times.

Comment: By "VR app for Samsung Gear", did you mean Oculus app? Also, just want to confirm from the tag, is the device Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge? Lastly, is your [Samsung Gear VR model compatible with Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge](https://www.samsung.com/uk/support/mobile-devices/which-galaxy-smartphones-are-compatible-with-which-gear-vrs/)?